# Mitigation Cap on Portals

Tags: ingress

Is there still the +95 cap on portal mitigation?

I have seen contradicting information in a few places and am not sure if it is still capped or not.  Anyone even have any anecdotal evidence from their own observations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From all the information available on Google+ and from players I have spoken to, the maximum mitigation on portals is capped at 95%

That isn't to say if a link drops or portal shields pop it will necessarily drop below 95 if the total remaining mitigation is still above 95.